# Обработчик кнопок JS ид кнопки равен ид заказу

Tags: javascript, jquery

имею проблему следующего характера.

Есть кнопка

```
<button id="button-history{{ order.order_id }}"  data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ button_history_add }}</button>
```

Где `{{ order.order_id }}`
равен ид заказу

Получаю следущий ид кнопки

```
button-history1259
```

Вопрос как мне сделать под нее обработчик(для каждого заказа).

По моей логике было все просто, а именно

```
$('button-history'+ zakaz_id).on('click', function() {
```

console.log('Клик');
});

Успешно послан далеко, ничего не происходит.

Делаю еще вот так:

```
(`#button-history${zakaz_id}`).on('click', function() {
```

console.log('Клик');
});

Также ничего не происходит.

Хотя в консоле, я получаю корректные значения.. но обработчик шлет меня куда подальше.

Подскажите как решить задчку такую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. добавить в button обработчик onclick и передать туда id
   onclick="handleClick(order.order_id)"
2. добавить в js файл функцию handleClick

   handleClick(id) {
   console.log(id)
   }

Ещё можно так:

```
$('.btn-primary').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    // здесь можно получить атрибут каждой кнопки
    const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  });
})
```

ну и соответственно добавить атрибут data-id в кнопку

```
<button data-id={{order.order_id}} class="btn-primary"></button>
```